# I want to link this bit of javascript to a button

Tags: javascript, html, button

```
<script>
var data = prompt("What year would you like the data for?");
if (data == 1901) {
    alert("26 thousand per million for males and 23 for females ");
} else if (data == 1910) {
    alert("23 thousand per million for males and 18 for females");
} else if (data == 1920) {
    alert("19 thousand per million for males and 15 for females");
} else if (data == 1930) {
    alert("17 thousand per million for males and 14.5 for females");
} else if (data == 1940) {
    alert("20 thousand per million for males and 15 for females");
} else if (data == 1950) {
    alert("15 thousand per million for males and 11 for females");
} else if (data == 1960) {
    alert("14.5 thousand per million for males and 9.5 for females");
} else if (data == 1970) {
    alert("14 thousand per million for males and 8 for females");
} else if (data == 1980) {
    alert("13 thousand per million for males and 5 for females");
} else if (data == 1990) {
    alert("10 thousand per million for males and 6 for females");
} else if (data == 2000) {
    alert("7 thousand per million for males and 5.2 for females");
} else if (data == 2010) {
    alert("7 thousand per million for males and 4.9 for females");

}else alert ("please enter a valid year from the chart.");

</script>
```

This is my javascript which obviously open's a prompt and requests a date but i want this prompt to become active on click of a button for example

To get the date [CLICK HERE] -----> "What year would you like the data for?"

how would i do this. also this button needs to go into html.

Comment: Get that code inside a function. Have the click event of the button call the function.

Comment: You may want to do some research and give it a try. Check out the "related" sidebar on this page. Show us your attempt and what went wrong. "Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include **attempted solutions**, **why they didn't work**, and the expected results."

Comment: Thank you very much that was a big help. Silly me was forgetting to put it in a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. Your logic is now inside a function, which is run when the click event is triggered on the button.

```
<script>
function yearData(){
  var data = prompt("What year would you like the data for?");
  if (data == 1901) {
    alert("26 thousand per million for males and 23 for females ");
  } else if (data == 1910) {
    alert("23 thousand per million for males and 18 for females");
  } else if (data == 1920) {
    alert("19 thousand per million for males and 15 for females");
  } else if (data == 1930) {
    alert("17 thousand per million for males and 14.5 for females");
  } else if (data == 1940) {
    alert("20 thousand per million for males and 15 for females");
  } else if (data == 1950) {
    alert("15 thousand per million for males and 11 for females");
  } else if (data == 1960) {
    alert("14.5 thousand per million for males and 9.5 for females");
  } else if (data == 1970) {
    alert("14 thousand per million for males and 8 for females");
  } else if (data == 1980) {
    alert("13 thousand per million for males and 5 for females");
  } else if (data == 1990) {
    alert("10 thousand per million for males and 6 for females");
  } else if (data == 2000) {
    alert("7 thousand per million for males and 5.2 for females");
  } else if (data == 2010) {
    alert("7 thousand per million for males and 4.9 for females");
  }else{
    alert("please enter a valid year from the chart.");
  }
}
</script>

<button onclick="yearData();">Get Year Data</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

May I suggest a bit of a cleanup?

```
var reportForYear = function(year) {
    var n = {
        1901: [26, 23],
        1910: [23, 18],
        1920: [19, 15],
        ⋮
    }[year];
    return !n ? "please enter a valid year from the chart."
        : n[0] + " thousand per million for males and " + n[1] + " for females";
};

var promptForYearAndReport = function() {
    var year = prompt("What year would you like the data for?");
    alert(reportForYear(year));
};
```

Then, on the button's onclick, call `promptForYearAndReport()`.

Comment: I suggested the edit `var promptForYearAndReport() {` to `var promptForYearAndReport = function() {` as currently your code won't work, but it got rejected....

Comment: +1 @RoryPicko92: Thanks for picking up on that one. I'm not sure why it was rejected.